# List layout issue inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have a layout problem - my `ScrollView` does not fill the whole screen, instead - the bottom half of the screen is not used with the scroll (my list updates dynamicly)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/newRecipeIngredientEditTextId" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:hint="Ingredient info" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/naddIngredientButtonId"></EditText>
    <Button android:text="@string/addNew" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/naddIngredientButtonId" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView12" android:layout_below="@+id/newRecipeIngredientEditTextId" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@android:id/android:list" android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just use listView, it has already scroll in it.

Comment: ListView in ScrollView ? not a good idea ... both are scrollable

Comment: I am using it inside a scroll so that scroll will be only on part of the screen and that user will not scroll the WHOLE screen - unless you can give me example how to do it (will be very helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Change RelativeLayouts width and height to Fill_Parent. And change ScrollView's Also